# DynamoDB ReturnValues UPDATED_OLD in AppSync

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync, vtl

Im trying to update an item attribute in a **DynamoDb** table with **AppSync**. 
Once successful i want to use the previous value of that attribute as the key in my next call (I'm using pipeline resolvers).

To achieve this with **DynamoDB** you just set **UPDATED_OLD** as the return value.

I cannot find any documentation for specifying the return value of a DynamoDB resolver for AppSync.
Ive tried the following.

```
{
  "version" : "2018-05-29",
  "operation" : "UpdateItem",
  "key": {
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson("foo")
      },
   "condition" : {
   "expression" : "attribute_exists(id)"
    },
    "update" : {
    "expression" : "SET bar = :bar",
    "expressionValues" : {
        ":bar" :  {"S" : "$bar"}
      }
    },
    "returnValues": "UPDATED_OLD"
  }
```

But its not valid syntax.

```
"message": "Unsupported element '$[returnValues]'."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returnValues is not a valid field for the request mapping template of AppSync with DynamoDB. By default AppSync uses the [ALL_NEW](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_RequestParameters) parameter for updates.

Comment: I was afraid that this were the case. Thank you for confirming it. Hopefully it will be rectified in some future update to make AppSync even more viable.

Comment: I will take it to the team as a feature request

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: @VasileiosLekakis Is there a Github issue associated with this feature request? This would be a valuable addition

Comment: @bingles we don't have track feature requests as Github issues at AWS Appsync like they do for AWS Amplify.

Comment: As for DeleteItem it return ALL_OLD, which makes sense.